# How references fields that are foreignkey in another table , Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

**Documents**
[models.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gGuxXPf62Lhvmoz4TE1ltd-APPRAtSm3)
[ERD-Restaurants](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/07a1fb02-a0c5-4f2c-bbaa-9f2509d8da5f)
python3.6.4, django 2.0

Hello django pals, I need some help.

This is the Rating class(Rating Table) in model.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):
     business = models.? r1
     dish = models.? r2
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
     rating = models.IntegerField()
     comment = models.TextField()
```

How can I references r1 with Price.restaurant, r2 with Price.dish? and set these 2 fields as primary key so that the 3 fields (business, dish and user) can form a composite key.

Is valid use the argument , primary_key=True  in ForeignKey fields as I am using there? Because I need to set that fields as primary key too.

Comment: Oh side note @christianbueno.1. If you wanted discrete values i.e. 1->5 stars you can modify your rating to be: `models.IntegerField(choices=star_choices)` where you have set this higher up: `star_choices = ((1, 'One star'),(2,'Two Stars'),(3,'Three Stars'),(4,'Four Stars'),(5,'Five Stars'))`. Or if you're feeling fun you could even have emojis in there! e.g. `((1,"⭐️"), ... ,(5,"⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️"))`

Comment: Thanks, I seams had read about that

Comment: must we enable anything for those emojis ?

Comment: I cannot be certain, if you are in windows < 10 and not in the browser, they may appear as square boxes. But windows >10, Mac, in any good browser will show emojis. They may not appear the same way as you intend, but star emojis are generally displayed decently [check here](https://emojipedia.org/white-medium-star/)

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM does not support multicolumn/composite primary keys. You need to use a surrogate key. See: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys

A possible solution:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together=('business','dish','user')

    business = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant...)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User...)
    comment = ...
```